# Function in Kotlin that takes the name of a month in input and returns the number of days for that month

Tags: kotlin

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

> Write a function in Kotlin that takes the name of a month in input and returns the number of days for that month (no need to worry about leap year for this exercise).
>
> Your "main" should print a statement similar to `The month of <month> has <number> of days`.

Code:

```
fun getDate(month:String, number:Int){
    
    var January =  31
    var February = 28  
    var March =  31
    var April =  30
    var May = 31
    var June = 30
    var July = 31
    var August = 31
    var September = 30
    var October = 31
    var November = 30
    var December = 31

    println("The month of $month has $number of days")
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    getDate("January")
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why was this tagged with JS?

Comment: I am trying to get it work but it doesn't work... so basically I am trying the user to write the input, let's say that he was January so it'll be something like "The month of <month> has <number> of days"

Comment: You need to read up (or ask your teacher) about the fundamentals of what a function is. There are too many things wrong with your code to explain without being able to build on that. A function takes inputs and optionally returns an output. Your function takes two inputs (the month and the number of days in a month) and produces no output, but your assignment was for a function that takes a single input (the month) and returns a single output (the number of days in that month).

Answer (score -3):

I think you're confusing strings and variable names. Variables with the names of months can't be compared with a `String` containing the name of a month.

For this problem, there are two solutions:

1. With many branches:

   ```
   fun getDate(month: String) {
       val number = when (month) {
           "January"   -> 31
           "February"  -> 28
           "March"     -> 31
           "April"     -> 30
           "May"       -> 31
           "June"      -> 30
           "July"      -> 31
           "August"    -> 31
           "September" -> 30
           "October"   -> 31
           "November"  -> 30
           "December"  -> 31
           else        -> throw RuntimeException("Invalid month")
       }
       println("The month of $month has $number of days")
   }
   ```
2. With a collection (in this example, a hashmap):

   ```
   val months = mapOf(
       "January"   to 31,
       "February"  to 28,
       "March"     to 31,
       "April"     to 30,
       "May"       to 31,
       "June"      to 30,
       "July"      to 31,
       "August"    to 31,
       "September" to 30,
       "October"   to 31,
       "November"  to 30,
       "December"  to 31
   )

   fun getDate(month: String) {
       val number = months[month] ?: throw RuntimeException("Invalid month")
       println("The month of $month has $number of days")
   }
   ```

Comment: 1-12 are not the number of days of a month.

Comment: Hi fellow, and do u know how can I return the number of days in the specific month? and how can I make the user write January... and how can print println("The month of $month has $number of days")

Comment: @forpas sorry, that was a mistake.